# Can you use a colon in a question?

Tags: grammar, questions, punctuation

Here is my sentence:

> Can you roll-back the fix: is that a possible option?

I feel like this follows the rules for a colon, since the first half could be a sentence by itself, and the second half can't be a sentence, because "that" refers to the first half.

However, I have never seen a colon in a question, so it seems wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean by "the rules for a colon". You seem to mean that "the first half could be a sentence by itself, and the second have [I assume you mean "half"] can't be a sentence". However, that's not a requirement for a colon. Can you explain?

Comment: "Is that a possible option?" is a valid sentence. Here "that" is a demonstrative pronoun.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan  I was referring to semi-colon vs colon rules. I understand that a if the two halves are complete sentences you use a semi-colon, if not you use a colon.

Comment: Two separate sentences seems fine in general, though.

Comment: @GC_ English style guides prescribe various rules, of course, but it is very common to allow a "complete sentence" to follow a colon. For example: "She explained why her stomach was growling: She hadn't eaten since breakfast." (Some guides would capitalize the second "she", while others wouldn't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is misuse of the colon.  You want it to splice together two independent clauses, but that's not what it's for.

Instead, write:

"**Can you roll-back the fix? Is that a possible option?**"

This is perfectly fine.  It is OK for "that" to refer to the action indicated in the previous sentence.

Think of a colon as a way of saying "*...and here it is*" before what follows: it signals a more complete statement of what was previously mentioned.

Comment: Feels like kind of redundant as two sentences.  However, I can't think of a better option.